# How to read widgetRenderingMode and other environmentVariants from an IntentTimelineProvider context

Tags: swift, widgetkit

I'm trying to ascertain the `widgetRenderingMode` and other context info from a widget timeline generator, but I see a weird build error with this code:

```
 func getTimeline(for configuration: AccessoryOptionsIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<AccessoryEntry>) -> Void) {
        
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) {
            if let mode: [WidgetRenderingMode] = context.environmentVariants.widgetRenderingMode {
                
            }
        }
```

`Cannot assign to property: 'environmentVariants' is a 'let' constant`
[image: Screenshot of Xcode build error]

How can I determine the rendering mode from the timeline?

See also: https://twitter.com/_DavidSmith/status/1578045086507696129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to read the current rendering mode, which can be read just like any other `EnvironmentValues` in SwiftUI.

```
@Environment(\.widgetRenderingMode) var widgetRenderingMode
```

I'm not sure why your code doesn't compile though. In theory, accessing `widgetRenderingMode` should compile because [`TimelineProviderContext.EnvironmentVariants`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineprovidercontext/environmentvariants-swift.struct) is marked with `@dynamicMemberLookup`. Your access would be turned into a key path and passed into [this subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineprovidercontext/environmentvariants-swift.struct/subscript(dynamicmember:)):

```
subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, T>) -> [T]? { get }
```

which is a read-only subscript and does not involve setting `environmentVariant`.

`TimelineProviderContext.EnvironmentVariants` does have [another subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineprovidercontext/environmentvariants-swift.struct/subscript(_:)) that *does* work for me:

```
subscript<T>(keyPath: WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, T>) -> [T]? { get }
```

You can use it like this:

```
if let mode = context.environmentVariants[\.widgetRenderingMode] {
    
}
```

Comment: This definitely fixes the build issue, but I think it doesn't return the active values, rather I believe it returns the possible values. `widgetRenderingMode: [fullColor, vibrant, accented]`. Am I missing something? If not, is there a way to see which timeline is being rendered?

Comment: @lewis "it returns the possible values" Well yeah, that's what `environmentVariants` is supposed to do. As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineprovidercontext/environmentvariants-swift.property) say, "All environment values that might be set when a widget appears". From what I understand, the actual rendering mode used is determined *later*. You can get this in your SwiftUI view using a `@Environment`.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, I saw that in the docs, but sometimes they just feel wrong. What's the point of knowing what it _could_ be?? (Not saying it's your fault obviously)

Comment: @lewis I thought you knew what the point was before you commented lol. Maybe there isn't a point for `widgetRenderingMode`  - this could be useful for other environment values.

Comment: "From what I understand, the actual rendering mode used is determined later" Do you have a source for this? It seems as tho the timeline is generated multiple times in quick succession, I assume it is generating for light/dark mode, etc. But maybe that is done after the fact. Thanks again.

Comment: @lewis It's just an educated guess - since from the `Context`, the only things that you can access that are not "all possible values" are `isPreview`, `family`, `displaySize`. It makes sense to think that only these are known at that time. Everything else is determined at a later stage.